# Range of $\log(16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the range of $f(x,y,z) = ln(16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2)$ 
 I know that the natural log function of one variable has range of all real numbers, so would this function be the same ? I tried to find it on Wolfram Alpha, however it said indeterminable.

Comment: Can you see that your function is bounded above?

Comment: No, I do not see that.Will you provide an algebraic method to prove that?

Comment: Can you show that $16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2$ is never greater than 1000?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I am about to go to sleep. This question just popped into my head, and it's really bothering me.

Comment: OK, maybe in the morning you'll see how to do it.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+log%2816-4x%5E2-4y%5E2-z%5E2%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{The argument of the log must be positive:}$$
$$\ 16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2>0$$
$$\ 4x^2+4y^2+z^2<16$$
$$\ \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{16}<1$$
$$\ (\frac{x}{2})^2+(\frac{y}{2})^2+(\frac{z}{4})^2<1$$
$$\text {so the domain is a region enclosed in an ellipsoid.}$$
$$\ \\ \text{Now you calculate what happens to the range 'moving in the domain':}$$
$$\text{note that }$$
$$\ log(16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2)=log[16-(4x^2+4y^2+z^2)]=log[16-p(x,y,z)]$$
$$\ \text{and }\ p(x,y,z)≥0 \forall(x,y,z).$$
$$\text{In the origin }p(x,y,z)=0 \text{ so you have the maximum value in the range: }$$
$$\ f(x,y,z)_{max}=log16$$
$$\text{Approaching the surface of the ellipsoid instead, the argument of the log tends to }\ 0^+$$
$$\text{so }\ f(x,y,z)\to -\infty$$
$$\text{The total range should be therefore: }\ (-\infty,log16]$$

Comment: I think you have found the *domain*, but OP asked for the *range*.

Comment: sorry,I was tricked by the word 'range', as I am not a native english speaker, I thought it was the same thing as 'domain'

Comment: Wait, but does the domain permit the values of x,y,z to go to infinity? Since the domain is the region enclosed within the ellipsoid, and the ellipsoid has a finite length on each axis, does that mean the values of x,y,z can't go to infinity ?

Comment: of course they cannot go to infinity, otherwise you would get a negative number in the argument of the log. If you look at the equation of the ellipsoid you will notice that -2<x<2; -2<y<2 and -4<z<4

Comment: I don't necessarily understand what you mean by, " Approaching the surface of the ellipsoid instead."

Comment: I mean that when p(x,y,z) tends to 16(which is the same thing as saying that you approach the ellipsoid surface), f(x,y,z) tends to -infinity because the argument of the log tends to 0-. I hope you understand now

Comment: Ah, yes -- okay I see what you're saying.. I've been up all night, so I'm a little turned around right now... However, I think you meant to put 0+ instead of 0-.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Note that the range of $g(x,y,z)=4x^2+4y^2+z^2$ is all non-negative real numbers.

Comment: So, since $4x^2+4y^2+z^2$ has range = $[0,+\inf)$ , if I multiply by -1, then I get $ -\inf<-4x^2-4y^2-z^2≤0$ I add 16, $ -\inf< -4x^2 - 4y^2 - z^2 + 16 ≤ 16$ then I take ln of both sides, but $ln(-\inf)$ only exists as a limit, right ? I'm a little tired, but I do recall that for the definition of a logarithm of u base q, q has to be greater than 0 and different than 1, and u has to be greater than 0 -- -inf is certainly not greater than 0.

Comment: You need to have $16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2\gt 0$ because $\ln X$ is defined only when $X\gt 0$. So, we have $0\lt 16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2\le 16\iff \ln (16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2)\le \ln 16$.

Comment: Can we just get rid of the 0 since ln(0) DNE ? What would then be the lower bound of this set ?

Comment: The range of $f(x,y,z)$ is $(-\infty,\ln 16]$. (Consider the case that $y=\ln X$ for $X\le \ln 16$. )

Comment: I think it may be more suitable to write $+0<f(x,y,z)≤C$ before taking the log, as the values of the polynomial can't include values approaching 0 that are negative, because this even powered polynomial won't allow that, then ln(+0) goes to −∞

Answer (score 0):

the domain of the function logx is (0,infinity) i.e., x>0

therefore the value inside the logarithm must be greater than zero which implies

$$16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2>0----(1)$$ $$4x^2+4y^2+z^2<16$$ which again implies $$\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}+\frac{z^2}{4^2}<1$$

if you consider it as an equation then you can see this is nothing but the equation of ellipsoid with center at origin.

therefore considering the expression inside logarithm $$16(1-\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}+\frac{z^2}{4^2})$$

lies in between 0 and 16 which implies the range is $$(-infinity,log16)$$